# Javascript loading content when scrolled to section

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, slide

I had a question about a particular feature i wanted to build with javascript/jQuery.

An example of the feature can be seen in the site below:
http://nicolasbouliane.com/

- If you scroll to the Example section, you can see how the content is loaded in when you get to the section and it has a transition (slides in)

How would i create something like this, or perhaps there are scripts out there?

Regards

Comment: This isn't the right place for plugin requests...

Comment: Not really requesting a plugin, but okay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done using skrollr.js

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

typical usage as simple as :

```
<div data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);" data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);">WOOOT</div>
```

where data-number represents current scroll position.

you may also wanna try:

http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

Comment: np glad i could help.